# Initialize variable in loop - use global variable?

Tags: python, global

I wrote a function that makes a screenshot and checks if it's different than the old one. The example code is below. However, I wonder about pythons best practice to set the variables oldimage and image. Especially oldimage needs to be set before main() can start the first time. Do I use global variables?

```
def main():
    image=screenGrab()
    if equal(image,oldimage):
        pass
    else:
        dosomething()
        oldimage=image

while True:
    main()
```

Comment: Why not just put the `while` loop *in the function*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using global variables is almost never the correct solution.  It usually ends up causing more problems than solutions.  Continuing from @MartijnPieters,  I would organize your code as follows:

```
def main():
    oldimage = loadLastImage()

    while True:
        image=screenGrab()
        if not equal(image,oldimage):
            dosomething()
            saveLastImage(image) # this is the opposite of loadLastImage()
            oldimage=image

# this is the more accepted way of running main 
# because it still allows your code to be loaded as module
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why have the `if not... pass`? It would be shorter to replace the `else` code with  `if equal...`.

Comment: Also, why have `oldimage=image`? That block of code is executing if `oldimage` and `image` are equal, so the reassignment isn't doing anything. Is that supposed to be in code that executes when they're *not* equal?

Comment: Not sure what happen on my answer submission.  I had taken out the unnecessary `pass` section, or at least i thought I had.  It has now been corrected.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thank you, that's propably the answer I needed! Works fine!